# I can't find my database that I have created When I am trying to upload an Excel file using import Export wizard

Tags: ssms

The issue is when I use sql import export server , When I select a Excel file. In the next step , it does not show the name of the database that I have created and where I want to store my file. It only shows a few options such as [Default],masterbd, tempdb and not the database in which I want to store this file.Thanks[image: I am attaching the image for reference]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which is your default database? Have a look at `master` database, maybe you'll find your table there.